# How to get the path of a CSV file inside Solution Exporer?

Tags: c#

I have a CSV file inside my solution explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]

How do I pass the path of file inside the Solution Explorer?

Code:

```
String filepath="C:\\Users\\vikas\\Desktop\\fetching.csv";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

in place of filepath passing file inside the Solution Explorer path.

Comment: Try using Server.MapPath("your file path here");

Comment: In Solution Explorer, click on the file and select the `Copy to Output Directory` property. Set it to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`, as you prefer/need to. Then you'll find the file in your `Application.StartupPath` (or any other way you can get to that path. `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`, for example).

Comment: Note that the path defined in Solution Explorer will be preserved: your file will be copied to `{Application.StartupPath}\Solution items\fetching.csv`.

Comment: can you write and give me the code

Comment: I don't think any of this will work if the file is in a solution folder and not within a project. The project doesn't know where the solution is. A project could be part of multiple solutions.

Comment: There's no code to give away. All is needed is already here. You need to move the `Solution Items` folder inside your Project, choose a copy method and that's all. You can find your file using one of the suggested way to get the executable path. i.e., `string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Solution Items\fetching.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

let us suppose you have a file called test.txt in a directory TestFolder

you can access it like this :

```
string filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\TestFolder\test.txt";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```